# How can I keep a div's scrollbar at the bottom of the div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, haml, sass

I have a div called #output, styled with **overflow: scroll;**. Using jQuery.ajax, it's being updated every x second. I'd *like* to have it so that when the scrollbar appears (after the divs filled up), it should continously stay at the bottom of the div instead of the top, like most chat clients do.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, I just can't seem to find it.

Here's the Sass

```
#output
  :margin 0 0 10px 0
  :padding 10px
  :height 500px
  :overflow scroll
  :background #111111
  :border 1px solid #000000
  :color #8e8e8e
```

and the Haml is just a simple

```
#output
  = @output
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#output").attr({ scrollTop: $("#output").attr("scrollHeight") });


$("#output").animate({ scrollTop: $("#output").attr("scrollHeight") }, 3000);  
// animated
```

See

[Using jQuery to Scroll to the bottom of an Element](http://www.kisdigital.com/index.cfm/2008/9/7/Using-jQuery-to-Scroll-to-the-bottom-of-an-Element)

Comment: I had seen that link, but it doesn't seem to work. I edited the question to include the Haml & Sass if it makes any difference.